# Cannot connect to MySQL using PHP 7

Tags: mysql, php, connectivity, mysql-8.0

The version of MySQL is 8.0.16. This is installed on an EC2 Linux and is a fresh install. I have run the `mysql_secure_installation` command after installation and was able to change the root password successfully and was also able to add a second user with basic privileges.

To test the connection I made a simple script:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);      
    if (mysqli_connect_error() ){
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo "Connection successful";
    }
```

I have double checked the values of the variables and they are all correct. When I try to visit the URL it says:

> Debugging errno: 2054

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-php) And this is because MySQL uses an authentication plugin. You can read all the details on the forum.

Comment: Would be great if you added a summary of what you actually did in your case. This site serves to help not only the person asking the question but also the wider community, and we prefer the answers to stand alone. References are great and encouraged, but it's still desirable to have the gist of the solution in the answer itself, cheers.